# Get userdata from url

Tags: urls, user-meta

I want to make a custom profile page.

So I would set a link from posts page using a simple hook, get the author, then a something like

```
     <a href="www.website.com/profile/<?php the_author(id); ?></a>
```

But how do I then retrieve this id from url for a profile page?

Get_var? or Get_object?

I would then want to display the users name, address, and other posts (custom post type) by the author.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress already has a url structure for Author information. If you have pretty Permalinks enabled, the URL should read like http://www.website.com/author/username .

You can make a new template file named author.php in your theme to manipulate what is shown on this page (add meta information and whatnot).

You can get the author id in the author.php by using `get_queried_object_id()` . Bonus: all the posts by this author are in the loop.

To get the URL for the authors page, you can use `get_author_posts_url( $author_id)` .